# LAN connection not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04

I am using static IP in my office and this is my ifconfig command output

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:ab:3a:db:a9:45  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4715 errors:0 dropped:14 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1424 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:399073 (399.0 KB)  TX bytes:121397 (121.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2218 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2218 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:178541 (178.5 KB)  TX bytes:178541 (178.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:07:15:ed:d4:f6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.224  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1184:6102:ad6e:c778/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16503 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12644015 (12.6 MB)  TX bytes:4011592 (4.0 MB)
```

now my problem is when I used static IP I am able to connect with other system in my network but unable to connect out of the network.
It is working fine if I am using LAN at my home because I am not using static IP.

Comment: This is probably not an IP address issue, but a routing issue. Add to your question the IP address of your router and the result of the `ip route show` command.

Comment: default via 192.168.14.1 dev enp2s0  proto static  metric 100 
192.168.14.0/24 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.14.45  metric 100

Comment: i think think this could be possible because of enp2s0 port

Comment: Where and how have you set the static IP address? What DNS nameserver did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your routing table.

When you try to reach a machine outside of your LAN, the data go first to the default router which takes care of the routing (i.e. sends the data to the next hop).

The default router is `192.168.14.1` that:

- is not on the `wlan0` LAN
- is on the `enp2s0` interface which is not configured (no IP address)